# Casting to String by parentheses gives crash on Android

Tags: java, android, string, casting, textview

I know how to get a String from a TextView with toString(), but i would like to understand why if i cast the TextView's text to String by parentheses, it leads Android to crash at runtime ?

e.g "`String text = (String)((TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId)).getText();"`

Comment: show us your stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the “toString()” you’re actually doing a conversion. You’re calling the objects toString() method who understands what the object is and how to convert it to a string which “makes sense”.

When you use the “(String)” syntax you’re using a cast which doe NO conversion. It just says take the object and, with no changes at all, treat it as though it were a String. Since the object is not a String, you can get errors calling methods which do not apply on what the object actually is.

Comment: Thank you, i thought that (String) was a shortcut to toString().

Comment: Glad to help. And the bad part is in some languages it _does_ mean conversion so I'm always extra careful not to fall into the trap.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `getText()` returns `CharSequence` (which you can cast to `Spannable` or `Editable` in some cases) which you cannot cast to `string` directly.

Using `toString()` gives you a conversion to `string` class.

From android developer documentation:

> public CharSequence getText ()
>
> Return the text the TextView is displaying. If setText() was called with an argument of BufferType.SPANNABLE or BufferType.EDITABLE, you can cast the return value from this method to Spannable or Editable, respectively. Note: The content of the return value should not be modified. If you want a modifiable one, you should make your own copy first.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 String text = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId)).getText().toString();
```

because getText() returns CharSequence object